# Where are the OpenCV development libraries installed?

Tags: matlab, ubuntu-studio, opencv

I need to install facedetect in matlab but it needs opencv library files and it has to be included during the compilation. So where is it? (In UbuntuStudio)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please install `libopencv-dev` first.

The library/header files are the in `/usr/include/opencv2`.